# How to write a same android application for both phone and tablet devices?

Tags: android, android-layout, tablet

I have two activities A and B in android application.On phone devices A launches into B.But I want to show both activities as fragments in the same activity on large tablets.

How to achieve this?Just writing different layouts won't work as logic will also change.So should I release two 'apks' for both phone and tablets?If not then how to write logic for both in the same application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to modify your design to use a single activity and two fragments. The two fragments are the "master" and "detail" which can be reused in both the tablet and phone versions. So for example, you can make `master.xml` and `detail.xml` layouts. Then you create different activity layouts for different devices sizes and/or orientations. For example, you can have a default `main.xml` in the `layout` folder and a `main.xml` for tablets in the `layout-large-land` folder.

You can do this all in a single APK. I suggest that you google "master detail for android". This is the name for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Create one class file, say **MyActivity.java**, write code to use phone fragment for phone and tablet fragment for tablet.

**Step 2:** Create two separate fragment classes, **phoneFragment.java** and **tabletFragment.java** which extends Fragment class.

**Step 3:** Create separate layouts for both fragments under layout directory, say **phoneFragment.xml** and **tabletFragment.xml**.

**Step 4:** Modify **activity_main.xml** to include both fragments.

And it's done!!

Here is an [Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm) with full description.

Comment: A careful design can reuse the same fragments in both the phone and tablet versions and use two different layouts for the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use fragments. They are part of the UI screen..Please watch the videos of the following link. They will help you a lot.

```
 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLonJJ3BVjZW4lMlpHgL7UNQSGMERcDzHo
```